# Function that can take a number or array of numbers as an argument and return a string or an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am creating a website that acts as a compound interest calculator. The user enters values in a form such as principal, interest rate, annual contribution, years of investment, etc... Calculations are then done with these values and later in the program displayed in a `<table>`.

The calculations require the dollar amount values to be of type `number`but when displaying these values in the `<table>` I need them to be formatted as a dollar amount and of the type `string.` I tried to create a function that can accept either a number or an array of numbers and return a string or an array of strings (the array part works fine, I cannot get the number part to work) :

```
/**
*formatAsDollarAmount takes a number or an
array of numbers and returns them formatted as strings "$xx.xx"
*@param x a number or an array of numbers 
*@return String "$xx.xx" or ["$xx.xx", "$xx.xx"]
*/
function formatAsDollarAmount(x){
  if(typeof(x) == 'number')
  {
    x = "$" + x.toFixed(2); //Doesn't work because strings are immutable? 
  }
  else if (Array.isArray(x)) {
    for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
      x[i] = "$" + x[i].toFixed(2); //toFixed(2) converts a number to a string keeping two decimal places (it also rounds properly).
    }
  }
  else{
    console.log("Error from formatAsDollarAmount()");
  }
}
```

An example of this function in use:

```
let balanceArray = [1000, 1070, 1060] //An array storing the balance of an investment year over year ($1000 in year 1, $1070 in year 2, $1060 in year 3)
let annualAddition = 100; //Contribute $100 annually
formatAsDollarAmount(balanceArray); //this statement works fine and the array will be equal to ["$1000", "$1070", "$1060"]
formatAsDollarAmount(annualAddition); //This statement does nothing
```

Now, I think the reason `formatAsDollarAmount();` is not working with a `number` as an argument has something to do with the immutability of strings, but I'm not sure?

Why isn't this function working with a `number` as an argument? Is there a way to have one function that can format both `number`s and `array`s the way I need or should I create two separate functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning from the function. In the case when input is an array, use map and in its callback concat `$` with the array element. `map` will return a new array.

```js
function formatAsDollarAmount(x) {
  if (typeof(x) == 'number') {
    return "$" + x.toFixed(2);
  } else if (Array.isArray(x)) {
    return x.map(item => "$" + item.toFixed(2))
  } else {
    console.log("Error from formatAsDollarAmount()");
  }
}
let balanceArray = [1000, 1070, 1060]
let annualAddition = 100;
console.log(formatAsDollarAmount(balanceArray));
console.log(formatAsDollarAmount(annualAddition));
```

Comment: I appreciate this response and it is working. However I am relatively new to javascript and I noticed that return `x.map(item => "$" + item.toFixed(2))` doesn't have a semicolon (`;`) at the end. Is there a reason for this? Or was it a typing error and javascript is just lenient/smart enough to understand what was intended?

Answer (score 1):

The reason passing a number instead of a string is not working, is because with an array of numbers, you are passing a reference to the array, so when you change the values you are changing the reference. When you pass a single number you are passing by value instead, there is no reference in this case.

You should return the values instead, so, use a map to map the items to a new array of strings, otherwise just return the number as a string in the desired format.

```js
function isValidNumber(val) {
  if (typeof val != 'number') throw new Error(`"${val}" is not a valid numeric value`)
  return true
}

function formatAsDollarAmount(val) {
  if (Array.isArray(val)) return val.map(i => isValidNumber(i) && `$${i.toFixed(2)}`)
  if (isValidNumber(val)) return `$${val.toFixed(2)}`
}

console.log(formatAsDollarAmount(1232))
console.log(formatAsDollarAmount([Math.random() * 100, 134, 3453, Math.random() * 100000]))
try {
  console.log(formatAsDollarAmount('asdf'))
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message)
}
```